# How can I implement double buffering in my c++ game?

Tags: c++, double-buffering

I have the problem of the flashing screen and I know that I need to use double buffering to fix it, but I don't know how and where to add it in my game. If for some reason I can't use it, is there any other way of reducing the flashing, because with the bigger maps it's getting worse. Here is part of the code:

```
    `const char HEIGHT=11, WIDTH=54;
     unsigned char maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]={

     "##############################",
     "#  !#      # ###  ##         #",
     "# ### ###  # !!  ### ####### #        GAME OF THRANS",
     "#     #    #####  ## # !!  # #",
     "######## #  ##     # ####  # #      R-restart  Q-quit",
     "#  !   # #   #  #  #       # #            M-menu",
     "### ## # ### #  #! #### ######",
     "#   !# #  ## #  ####  # # !! #                  W",
     "# #### ## ## #   #    # #### #      Controls:  A-S-D",
     "#         ##   #   #         #",
     "##############################",
     };

     enemy1.x=14;
     enemy1.y=7;
     enemy2.x=22;
     enemy2.y=9;
     enemy3.x=10;
     enemy3.y=3;


      srand(time (NULL));

     while(on){

maze[ppy][ppx]=playerSprite;
maze[gpy][gpx]=goal;
maze[enemy1.y][enemy1.x]=enemy1.sprite;
maze[enemy2.y][enemy2.x]=enemy2.sprite;
maze[enemy3.y][enemy3.x]=enemy3.sprite;

for(int y=0; y<HEIGHT;y++){
    cout<<endl;
    for(int x=0;x<WIDTH;x++){
        cout<<maze[y][x];
    }
}
     for(;;){

randNum=rand()%randNumMax+1;
cout<<endl;


        movement=getch();
        switch (movement){
    case'w':
        if (maze[ppy-1][ppx]!='#' &&(maze[ppy-1][ppx]==' '||(maze[ppy-1][ppx]=='G','N','M','Y','!'))){
            maze[ppy][ppx]=' ';
            ppy--;
            moves++;
             if (maze[ppy][ppx]=='!'){
                Beep(400,150);
                points++;

             }`
```

Comment: Outputting many characters with `cout` is gonna give you flashing screens/whateveryouwannacallit. If you want to use "console graphics", you should use `curses` (specifically: `ncurses` for Linux and `pdcurses` for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do "double buffering" in the usual sense with standard C++ console io. With graphics, double buffering traditionally means doing all your rendering to an offscreen back-buffer and then switching it with the front-buffer during the v-blank to avoid flickering. There's nothing directly equivalent to that for console output in standard C++.

You could try something "in the spirit" of double buffering. Build up your final string using a `stringstream` rather than outputting directly to `cout` and then display the entire string in one go using one write to `cout`. This might reduce your flickering.

As a side note, you probably want to avoid using `endl` after each line of your output since it flushes the output stream which is not what you want. Use `'\n'` instead and only use `endl` when you actually want to flush at the end of your 'frame'.